# New to using openCV in python, I tried copying a code from a youtube tutorial to understand it better, but it isn't working for me why is that?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I'm new to the OpenCV library and I'm trying to learn it. As part of it I tried just using someone's code and testing it on my own computer. The code is identical to that of the video, yet does not work on my computer as it does nothing after I run it, with a message saying the camera index is out of range. I've attempted to fix this but to my knowledge all applications have camera access. It is also the first time I attempt anything with cameras. Here is the code I copied,

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Screenshot in Python")

img_counter = 0

while True:

    ret,frame = cam.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("test",frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k%256 == 27:
        print("Escape hit, clossing the app")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name,frame)
        print("Screenshot taken")
        img_counter +=1
cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried allowing access to camera to all apps and changing the camera index to no avail. it is my first time ever working with camera/code interaction so please be patient, thank you.

Comment: Is your filename saved in a folder?

Comment: @toyotaSupra sorry, new to phyton, this worked.